# Unneeded information at beginning of XCode Console output

Tags: xcode, console

I know this has probably been asked, but I can't find the answer.

How do I get rid of this from the beginning of my XCode console output? So that it just shows what I intentionally print to the screen?

```
[Session started at 2011-04-10 18:37:40 +0100.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1510) (Fri Oct 22 04:12:10 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty              /dev/ttys001
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-11063-56
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
```

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 4, change "All output" to "Target Output".
I'm still looking for a solution for Xcode 3 ...

Answer (score 1):

In response to "where is that?"

[image: location]

Now, if only there were a way to automatically delete all of Apple's **asinine** legal disclaimers from the top of EVERY SINGLE PIECE OF THEIR SAMPLE CODE.  Ugh!